# prior art for US patent 7438306 motorcycle patent with overly broad claims

Tags: prior-art-request, steering, suspension, motorcycle, neck

I am looking for prior art for [US patent 7438306](http://www.google.co.in/patents/US7438306)
I belive this patent may have overly broad claims
There is an AME kit that may have a german patent that is prior art

Answer (score 1):

My tools that I use are restricted to the USPTO at this time, all results found are from there.

https://www.google.com/patents/US7111861

The above invention uses a pneumatic piston (as opposed to a semi-perpendicular rod setup) to achieve the same effect.

https://www.google.com/patents/US5967538

The above invention uses a pivot ball (as opposed to a semi-perpendicular rod setup) to achieve the same effect.

https://www.google.com/patents/US8720928

The above invention uses interchangeable pucks to achieve the same effect.

https://www.google.com/patents/US5209319

The above invention uses a bar system to provide a stiff brace, but is not related.

https://www.google.com/patents/US7360963

The above invention can fixedly change the rake angle, but is not related.